# How to compile the solidity source code for getting the soljson.js file?

Tags: solidity

Solidity's reposite: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity;
I want convert the cpp code to javascript using emscripten. But I don't know whether there is a script in above reposite, if yes, how could I run it? I haven't found the doc to describe it. Could you tell me? Thanks very much!

Comment: which cpp code? you want to convert into JS and why?

Comment: The code is in the reposite I listed above. And in remix, we compile contract using the js compiler which is converted from the cpp code.  Now I have modified the cpp code for my special requirement. And the next step is getting the js code which is used in web frontend.